# Finding change in knapsack

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Currently, there's 6 questions tagged [change-making-problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-making-problem): one in 2012, two last year and three this year so far.

This kind of problem is closely associated with (or rather, a subset of) the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), and yet we don't have a tag for that. What's also crucial to note is that usually, the coin/knapsack problem is about finding the *minimum* number of coins/items, and I think there's at least [two](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118006/converting-money-into-change) [questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121700/given-a-monetary-amount-calculate-the-equivalent-change) that don't fit...

Should we create a [knapsack-problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knapsack-problem) tag and make [change-making-problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-making-problem) a synonym, and at the same time un-tag the two questions?

**edit:** if we go by a simple [knapsack search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=knapsack), there are already 33 questions.

Comment: I've considered it. Whether or not change-making is a knapsack problem depends on the specific set of denominations, though.

Comment: If you start adding problem categories like knapsack, then you also open yourself up to traveling salesman, fizzbuzz, and dozens of  other categories.  Additionally, this requires that users (many of which aren't CS trained) be able to recognize that their problem is a variation of some classic CS problem in order to correctly tag the question.

Comment: @Zack That's a good thing. We do have [tag:fizzbuzz], [tag:travelling-salesman], and dozens of other categories. Having human experts tag questions to help locate non-obvious search results is helpful — perhaps one of the most important benefits of tagging.